# With or without quotes in dataframes with R

Tags: r, string

I am trying to do a sentiment analysis system using Naive Bayes. In the train data I have a dataframe like this:

```
[1] "good"       "bad"           "ugly"       "not too bad"       "so bad"       "too bad"       "very good"          
   [8] "good"       "too bad"       "good"       "too bad"       "too bad"           "good"       "too bad"
```

And in the test data, I have a dataframe like this:

```
[1] good      too  bad           too  ugly       not too bad       so bad       too bad       very good          
   [8] good       too bad       so good       too bad       too bad           good       too bad
```

As you can see in the test dataframe I have sentiment words without " ". Will this cause any problems?

EDIT:

Here the R code :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(text2vec)
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
library(ggrepel)
library(Matrix)
library(tm)
library(RTextTools)
library(e1071)

Train_classifier1 <- read.csv('IRC.csv',header=T, sep=";")
Train_classifier2 <- read.csv('IRC_ag_2014_s2.csv',header=T, sep=";")
Train_classifier3 <- read.csv('IRC_ag_2015_s1.csv',header=T, sep=";")
Train_classifier4 <- read.csv('IRC_ag_2015_s2.csv',header=T, sep=";")

Train1 <- Train_classifier1[, c("Note.Reco", "Raison.Reco")]
Train2 <- Train_classifier2[, c("Note.Reco", "Raison.Reco")]
Train3 <- Train_classifier3[, c("Note.Reco", "Raison.Reco")]
Train4 <- Train_classifier4[, c("Note.Reco", "Raison.Reco")]

Train_classifier <- rbind(Train1, Train2, Train3, Train4)

# select only 4 column of the dataframe

#Train <- Train_classifier[, c("Note.Reco", "Raison.Reco")]
#, "DATE_SAISIE", "idpart")]

#delete rows with empty value columns
Train <- Train_classifier[rowSums(Train_classifier == '') == 0,]
Train$ID <- seq.int(nrow(Train))

Train


# # replacing class values
Train$Note.Reco = ifelse(Train$Note.Reco >= 0 & Train$Note.Reco <= 4, "super détracteur", ifelse(Train$Note.Reco >= 5 &
Train$Note.Reco <= 6, "détracteur", ifelse(Train$Note.Reco >= 7 & Train$Note.Reco <= 8, "neutre", "prometteur")))

p <- as.vector(Train[1:41789,2])
matrix = create_matrix(p, language = "french", removeStopwords = TRUE, removeNumbers = TRUE, stemWords = FALSE)
sparse_DTM <- removeSparseTerms(matrix, 0.98)
mat=as.matrix(sparse_DTM)

classifier = naiveBayes(mat[1:40000,], as.factor(Train[1:40000,1]))

predicted = predict(classifier, mat[40001:41789,]); predicted
#mat[40001:41789,]
table(Train[40001:41789,1 ], predicted)
recall_accuracy(Train[40001:41789,1 ], predicted)
```

Comment: Looks like the class in the first dataframe is character and factor in the second. Can you call `sapply(df, class)` with both your data frames as df?

Comment: All of them are factors

Comment: @Harald I just edit my post by adding the r code, thanks